# Unexpected results in eloquent query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, relational-database, eloquent

I am running the following query in my laravel code,

```
$organisations = Organisation::with('projects', 'projects.clients')
                     ->with('clients')
                     ->get();

    $organisations->load('users');
```

This is loading in my organisations table, and should in thoery load in any related models as well so I would expect an object that looks like this to be returned,

```
organisation {
     projects {
         clients {

         }
     }
     users {

     }
}
```

Basically an organisation can have many projects, a project can have one client, an organisation can also have many users and many clients.

What I am wanting from my query is for the client data to returned with each project but I am not getting that, currently I am getting the following object returned.

```
[
    {
        "id": "114",
        "name": "XXXXXXX",
        "slug": "XXXXXXX",
        "information": "",
        "type": "organisation",
        "notifications": "0",
        "add_all": "0",
        "created_at": "2014-12-16 10:16:03",
        "updated_at": "2014-12-16 10:16:03",
        "clients": [
            {
                "id": "39",
                "name": "Simon's Test",
                "information": "",
                "address": null,
                "website": null,
                "email": null,
                "phone": null,
                "type": "client",
                "add_all": "0",
                "created_at": "2014-12-16 10:16:20",
                "updated_at": "2014-12-16 10:16:20",
                "user_id": "1",
                "owner_id": "114",
                "projects": [
                    {
                        "id": "56",
                        "name": "iOS Application",
                        "description": "An iOS application that will be available on iPhone and iPad. Something that will change the way we manage projects.",
                        "total_cost": "5000.00",
                        "start_date": "2014-01-01",
                        "finish_date": "2014-12-10",
                        "status": "1",
                        "sales_person": null,
                        "project_manager": null,
                        "client_id": "39",
                        "organisation_id": "114",
                        "owner_id": "114",
                        "user_id": "1",
                        "created_at": null,
                        "updated_at": "2014-12-15 13:20:07"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "57",
                        "name": "Android Application",
                        "description": "An android application that will run on any android phone, upto a certain version.",
                        "total_cost": "6500.00",
                        "start_date": "2015-01-31",
                        "finish_date": "2015-03-19",
                        "status": "2",
                        "sales_person": null,
                        "project_manager": null,
                        "client_id": "39",
                        "organisation_id": "114",
                        "owner_id": "114",
                        "user_id": "1",
                        "created_at": null,
                        "updated_at": "2014-12-11 15:01:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "58",
                        "name": "Java Application",
                        "description": "A windows phone application, to be released for the small market share that market has.",
                        "total_cost": "7500.00",
                        "start_date": "2014-12-12",
                        "finish_date": "2014-12-31",
                        "status": "3",
                        "sales_person": null,
                        "project_manager": null,
                        "client_id": "39",
                        "organisation_id": "114",
                        "owner_id": "114",
                        "user_id": "1",
                        "created_at": null,
                        "updated_at": "2014-12-11 15:01:15"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "59",
                        "name": "OSX Application Beta",
                        "description": "A desktop application for the Mac. More feature rich than the native iOS apps, more like the web application for desktop.",
                        "total_cost": "20000.00",
                        "start_date": "2014-11-20",
                        "finish_date": "2014-12-19",
                        "status": "2",
                        "sales_person": null,
                        "project_manager": null,
                        "client_id": "39",
                        "organisation_id": "114",
                        "owner_id": "114",
                        "user_id": "1",
                        "created_at": null,
                        "updated_at": "2014-11-28 16:01:41"
                    }
                ],
                "users": []
            }
        ],
        "projects": [
            {
                "id": "56",
                "name": "iOS Application",
                "description": "An iOS application that will be available on iPhone and iPad. Something that will change the way we manage projects.",
                "total_cost": "5000.00",
                "start_date": "2014-01-01",
                "finish_date": "2014-12-10",
                "status": "1",
                "sales_person": null,
                "project_manager": null,
                "client_id": "39",
                "organisation_id": "114",
                "owner_id": "114",
                "user_id": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2014-12-15 13:20:07",
                "pivot": {
                    "organisation_id": "114",
                    "project_id": "56"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "57",
                "name": "Android Application",
                "description": "An android application that will run on any android phone, upto a certain version.",
                "total_cost": "6500.00",
                "start_date": "2015-01-31",
                "finish_date": "2015-03-19",
                "status": "2",
                "sales_person": null,
                "project_manager": null,
                "client_id": "39",
                "organisation_id": "114",
                "owner_id": "114",
                "user_id": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2014-12-11 15:01:15",
                "pivot": {
                    "organisation_id": "114",
                    "project_id": "57"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "58",
                "name": "Java Application",
                "description": "A windows phone application, to be released for the small market share that market has.",
                "total_cost": "7500.00",
                "start_date": "2014-12-12",
                "finish_date": "2014-12-31",
                "status": "3",
                "sales_person": null,
                "project_manager": null,
                "client_id": "39",
                "organisation_id": "114",
                "owner_id": "114",
                "user_id": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2014-12-11 15:01:15",
                "pivot": {
                    "organisation_id": "114",
                    "project_id": "58"
                }
            },
            {
                "id": "59",
                "name": "OSX Application Beta",
                "description": "A desktop application for the Mac. More feature rich than the native iOS apps, more like the web application for desktop.",
                "total_cost": "20000.00",
                "start_date": "2014-11-20",
                "finish_date": "2014-12-19",
                "status": "2",
                "sales_person": null,
                "project_manager": null,
                "client_id": "39",
                "organisation_id": "114",
                "owner_id": "114",
                "user_id": "1",
                "created_at": null,
                "updated_at": "2014-11-28 16:01:41",
                "pivot": {
                    "organisation_id": "114",
                    "project_id": "59"
                }
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "id": "1",
                "email": "simon@pikcells.com",
                "first_name": "Simon",
                "last_name": "Ainley",
                "display_name": "simonainley",
                "initials": "SA",
                "remember_me": null,
                "active": "1",
                "invite_code": null,
                "forgotten_code": null,
                "login_type": "normal",
                "api_token": null,
                "created_at": "-0001-11-30 00:00:00",
                "updated_at": "2014-12-12 11:53:53",
                "deleted_at": null,
                "pivot": {
                    "organisation_id": "114",
                    "user_id": "1",
                    "is_admin": "1"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

In the object above you can see that I get the organisations projects and clients returned to me, but the clients have nested projects, i.e what projects they are related too, but I would like to return projects nested with the clients they are related too is this possible?

Comment: Yes, the code you show will return what you expect. Show the relations and the execution, where you output that json result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note about the naming. If your projects can only have one client the relationship would better off if called "client" instead of "clients".

Project Model

```
//Client relationship in Project model
 client()
 {
    $this->belongsTo('Client')
 }
```

this way is more readable and you can call it like this

```
Organisation::with('projects.client', 'clients', 'users')->get()
```

you need the relationships projects, clients and users in the Organisation model.

Check the [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) documentation for more info about relationships

Answer (score -1):

```
$organisations = Organisation::with(array('Projects'=>function($q){
                      $q->with('Client')
                 },'Clients','Users'))->get()                                          

You can fetch expected output using above code

You have to define 3 relationships in Organization model : Projects,Clients,Users
You have to define 1 relationship in Project model : Client
```

Comment: That closure is redundant.

Comment: Hey can you explain how it is redundant ?

Comment: `with('projects.client')` is enough. The closure you suggested is used to add constraints on the relation query, no need for that when you just want to load nested relations.